# Sharp JS: Error with input as Buffer made from base64

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharp

I was trying to create an API endpoint for rotating images uploaded from client side. I'm sending images as base64 type, converted from blob (from simple <input tag), as follows:

```
const addImageBase64 = async (fileData) => {
   const file = fileData;

   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     const reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = (event) => {
       resolve(event.target.result);
     };
     reader.onerror = (err) => {
       reject(err);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   });
};
```

Then, on the server side, that's how the endpoint looks like:

```
app.post("/api/rotate-image", async (req, res) => {
   try {
     let buffer = Buffer.from(req.body.imageData, "base64");   //not working
     let array = new Uint8Array(buffer);                       //not working
     
     const image = await sharp(buffer)
       .rotate(180)
       .png({ quality: 100 })
       .toBuffer();

     console.log("success");
     res.status(200).send({
       success: true,
       result: image,
     });
   } catch (e) {
     console.warn(e);
   }
 });
```

And here, every my attempt is ending up with **'[Error: Input buffer contains unsupported image format]'** - either for Buffer or Uint8Array. Can anyone help me with this issue? What is the right input type for Sharp that acctually works?

Edit:
Error with logged buffer obj:
[image: Error with logged buffer obj]

Comment: Sharp [seems](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/9f2f92095db8b951da9fa451e697dea2ae22119f/test/unit/io.js#L338-L358) to return that error if Buffer is empty or does not contain valid JPEG, PNG, etc. image. Please check that `req.body`  has correct value and add body-parser as in [this example](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#express-route-specific) if needed.

Comment: @Vitalii, I made a screenshot with buffor object logged - seems like it contains some data. (please look at the edited post). I tested it with few images, all with the same error as a result.

Comment: interesting, maybe somethings is wrong on upload side. Your buffer starts with `75 ab 5a` but common images should start with `FF D8 FF` (JPEG) or `89 50 4E` (PNG), etc. (see [list of signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures))

Comment: Try `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)` instead of `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`

Comment: I've reviewed FileReader [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#methods) and looks like `reader.readAsText(file, 'base64')` is what you need instead of `reader.readAsDataURL(file)`

Comment: Unfortunetely `reader.readAsText(file, 'base64')` also ends up with some inaccurate buffer's content. What I've found out, thanks for your ideas, the best way is to use  `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)`. But by using the JSON.stringify while preparing the body of the request, each element of the array is converted to object that looks like key-value-pair. ("1": "89", "2":"50" ...) Thus it is needed to reiterate the whole thing again on the server side, and rebuild the array structure. Seems not optimal, but it works now. :)